# Bounding solution to elliptic problem with inhomogeneous Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am having a hard time understanding the passage at the end of page 478 and the beginning of page 479 from [Blowing up solutions for an elliptic Neumann problem with sub- or supercritical nonlinearity. Part II : $N\geq 4$](http://www.numdam.org/articles/10.1016/j.anihpc.2004.07.004/) by Rey & Wei.

In short, their argument is as follows: let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ ($N\geq 2$); $\mu>0$ and suppose that $u\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ satisfies
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u+\mu u=0 &\text{in}~\Omega;\\
\partial_\nu u=g &\text{on}~\partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
They then proceed to say that *standard elliptic theory* implies a bound on $\|u\|_\infty$ in function of $g$. Unfortunately, I have been unable to identify which result would let one deduce such a conclusion.